Connecting Excel to MySQL Database through Power Query
I am trying to connect Excel to a MySQL database using Power Query by following this path: Data > Get Data > From Database > From MySQL Database.
System Details:

Operating System: Windows Server 2022
Microsoft Excel Version: 2021

Issue:
Despite having installed various versions of the ODBC driver, I still receive a prompt indicating that a connector is needed.
Screenshots:
enter image description here
enter image description here
Steps Taken:

Installed multiple versions of the ODBC driver
Checked the firewall

Question:

Is there a specific connector I need to install or a particular setting in Excel that needs adjustment to resolve this issue?

Is there a setting you need to change in the firewall

Tried installing different versions of the ODBC driver

Checked the firewall


the prompt below should show
enter image description here
